# Encrypting password causes MySQL unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql

OK so I am trying to create user authentication for a little Java project of mine and I've run into a bit of a road block.
I have a table called user_info with 3 columns; id, user and password.

I realized that I should probably have some form of encryption, so I used Java's MessageDigest to encrypt the password with SHA1. Since I don't yet have a website for people to register (and have PHP enter the encrypted PW into the database), I simply encrypted a test password and replaced the unencrypted password in the database with the encrypted one.

For example, a user with username test and password test has an encrypted password of:
895df4f75b316de68d167ed2e83adb0bedbbde17

So my database has an entry with id 0, user test and password 895df4f75b316de68d167ed2e83adb0bedbbde17.

Now my Java code to check if the person provided valid details had no issue until I started using encrypted passwords.

Here is the login code for my Java application:

```
public int doLogin(String username, String pass) {
    EncryptionHandler e = new EncryptionHandler();

    String userToLogIn = username;
    String userToLogInPassword = pass;

    try {
        String fixedUser = prepString(userToLogIn);
        String fixedPass = e.doEncryptPassword(prepString(userToLogInPassword));
        System.out.println(fixedPass);

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `user` = " + fixedUser + " AND `password` = " + fixedPass);

        if (rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getString(1) + ", USER: " + rs.getString(2) + ", PASSWORD: " + rs.getString(3));
            return 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username or password is invalid!");
            return 0;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private String prepString(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder().append("'").append(s).append("'").toString();
}
```

and in case it's needed, my encryption method:

```
public String doEncryptPassword(String s) {
    MessageDigest sha1;
    try {
        sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] digest = sha1.digest((s).getBytes());
        return bytes2String(digest);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return s;

}
private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        String hexString = Integer.toHexString(0x00FF & b);
        string.append(hexString.length() == 1 ? "0" + hexString : hexString);
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

Again, using unencrypted passwords works just fine, but as soon as I encrypt the password I get the unknown column error. In this example (user test, password test), passing the unencrypted password receives no error, but using the encrypted password 895df4f75b316de68d167ed2e83adb0bedbbde17 provides me the error:
Unknown column '895df4f75b316de68d167ed2e83adb0bedbbde17' in 'where clause'

Comment: Careful with SQL injections. Also, don't quote your column names, quote your strings.

Comment: You are not encrypting (two-way function) you are hashing (one-way function).  The point of a hash is that you _cannot_ recover the password from it.

Comment: Ignoring that this isn't encryption, you have invalid SQL because you aren't quoting the hashed password string. Of course **you should never create SQL like that in the first place.**. Use prepared statements -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Re: *you aren't quoting the hashed password string.* More specifically, you need to quote the value **after** its hashed, not the other way around. But as others mentioned, you should really use prepared statements instead. It is much simpler and safer.

Comment: @Leigh - it's not a hashed password string until ... after it's been hashed. Before that, it's just a password string ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach - Yep. What I meant was they are quoting the plain value first, then hashing, and wondering why the quotes disappear ;-) They need to hash first, *then* quote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring that this isn't encryption, you have invalid SQL because of quoting problems. As @Leigh notes in the comments, you put quotes at the beginning and end of your password string ... then hash it. Your quotes are now dearly departed.

Of course you should **never create SQL like this in the first place**. Use prepared statements -> [Oracle Prepared Statements Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Get rid of any of your own home-grown string quoting then simply do:

```
String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlString);
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, hashedPassword);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Alright, that worked out perfectly. And to those that said it isn't encryption or I'm doing SQL wrong, I'm pretty new to all this internet stuff and I don't really know these exact specifics. New to MySQL and PHP in general so I am bound to make mistakes.

However, I do appreciate the feedback you guys left me and will most certainly learn from my mistakes that I made.

Comment: Yeah, we have all made similar mistakes over the years. The reason for pointing them out is that understanding *why* much is more important than just having the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your prepString thingy as well for the password:

```
    String fixedPass = prepString(e.doEncryptPassword(userToLogInPassword));
```

But it isn't a good idea to build statements this way.
Use prepared statements.

Comment: Should properly skip the inner prepString all together.

Comment: Re: *But it isn't a good idea to build statements this way. Use prepared statements.* That is the best advice. Quoting would be a non-issue if you were using prepared statements. Plus it is more secure.